# Vuforia + QR code scanner + Image targets

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, vuforia

Is it possible to scan QR code, get info from it and show 3D model on qr code frame?

I made project where some qr code can be loaded as image tracker, but how show 3D model using info from ANY qr code (programmatically) ?

```
    void qrCodeResult(String qrCodeText) {
       if (qrCodeText.equals("HULK")) {
          showHulk3DModel();// this model should be bind to the qr code frame
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you make it a little more clear - you say you are able to identify with Vuforia any QR code as an image, and you just want to be able to read the info from the QR code?

Comment: @yakobom I want read QR code info and show 3D model on it.
NOT to load image with qr code into vuforia database (it is easy)

Comment: Thus I want to read only info from QR code and do not have any database with images

Comment: If you do not have any database why do you need Vuforia? This does not make any sense. Either you use Vuforia, with pre-determined images, or you use some other tracking library if you wish the 3D model to track the QR code

Comment: And which library can you suggest? I need to build Android 4.4+ app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vuforia, or any similar SDKs, require a database with the images, so you cannot really use it to track just any QR code. So you cannot really do what you want with such SDKs.

The main options I see are:

1. If possible product-wise, attach the QR code to an image that Vuforia can track. This way you will be able to track it, and get information about the location in order to place your 3D model. There is one major complexity here - in order to read the QR code, you will have to use some QR library, such as xzing, and on each frame to take the image from Vuforia (they have API for that) and pass it to the QR library in order to try and read it.
2. The harder option - use some image processing library, such as OpenCV, to identify and track the QR code. For identifying the QR code and reading it you can find quite a few code samples on the web.

Comment: Can I just spawn 3D Cube in world and look on it through the camera? Without any images trackers and other

I try to call BuildNewTarget() method from UDTEventHandler.cs script but can't see nothing on the display

Comment: Not really... you need the xyz position of the qr code, unless you want to show the model at a constant location, not on the qr code